# Create a enum table and access it from other table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema as follows:

> [enumeration]
>
> Status{
>
> good, bad, high,low
>
> }
>
> Image{
>
> ```
> id :string
> name: string
> quality : Status
> ```
>
> }

I have found that enum Table can be created as:

Create Table Status{
   status enum ('good','bad','high','low')
 };

My question: Do i need to create a column for a table Status? 
             How can i refer it in other table while creating a table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a table for status. You declare a status enum column in your image table. Like so:

```
create table testo (status enum('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
insert into testo(status) values('foo');
```